# TTreeView makes IHM freezed when is expanded

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe6

I have an application written in DELPHI 5, recently we decided to migrate to the latest version of DELPHI (DELPHI XE6).
with some adaptation and modification we succusfully compiled and run the Application. However we are using a TTrevview component, when this componenet is expanded , any action on other components ( button, menus ..) make the interface to be freezed.

Comment: That suggests that your code is likely doing something to prevent the main thread from processing new messages from the main message queue. But without seeing your actual code, we can only assume what is actually happening.  Presumably your D5 code works fine, so I suspect the problem may be related to the "adaptation and modification" that you had to do for XE6.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong in your code. It's impossible to say what that might be, however, because *you provided no code in your question*, and I can't quite read your screen from here. (I also have no idea what you mean by "IHM". You might either explain the term in your question body or remove it from your title.)

Comment: In fact it is the call of the `Application.proccessMessage` that makes this strange behaviour.